# Power AI: connect ECONNREFUSED 35.227.52.17:8000

Tags: connection, ip, vpn, internet-connection

When i upload my data into Power AI and start to train the model, one problem occurred.

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 35.227.52.17:8000
```

I try different datatypes, but it still failed. I have googled about ECONNREFUSED problems but with different numbers behind (see below), which results are all about connections.

```
35.227.52.17:8000
```

So i guess it's VPN problem (cause i am in China). I try 2 VPN, but still failed. So, i am wondering whether i should change another VPN?